Ubuntu 20.04 loses DNS Settings
I have a problem with several Ubuntu 20.04 servers and their DNS settings. From time to time they loose their DNS Settings and will use an internal DNS fallback server, which was never configured by myself.
When the DNS falls back to the public DNS server my whole internal DNS services will fail and the different applications can't find the right IPs.
I use the netplan option to configure my IP, dns-server and systemd-
resolve as DNS client.
Failed DNS:

How it should be:

netplan config:

Results of systemd-resolv --status:

When the DNS client switches from my two network internal DNS server to the localhost  dns-service, the IP of the internal DNS Server switches from 192.168.1.x to 127.0.0.53, but systemd-resolv shows my two static configured DNS servers as used DNS servers.
resolv.conf points to 127.0.0.53:

(DHCP with DNS is not used in that case, the IPs are configured static on the servers)

Is this problem known?
What can I do to prevent Ubuntu from switching to the fallback option?
Is there a option to reconfigure the internal fallback server from Ubuntu?


Please, don't post screenshots. Instead copy and paste the relevant (the shorter the better) text from your terminal and paste it into your question by putting it inside ```.
